# checkout onepage review item file override issue

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, paypal-express, renderer

I am trying to override the review/item.phtml file of checkout module into my custom module.

**app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\checkout_onepage_review_item_renderers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="checkout_item_price_renderers"/>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.onepage.review.item.renderers">
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" name="checkout.onepage.review.item.renderers.test" template="Vendor_Module::onepage/review/item.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Then created the template file inside this path.

**app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\templates\onepage\review\item.phtml**

The above approach is not working, can anyone help me with overriding the above mentioned file into my custom module.

Looks like I am using the correct code, Please correct and help me with the right code if there is any mistake.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Generally we override phtml file in custom module using following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance dc" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.onepage.review.item.renderers.test">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::onepage/review/item.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

Please check in this way.

Thank you